# Performance test fails in Kafka with kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh

Tags: apache-kafka, performance-testing

Trying to do performance tests in Kafka with `kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh`, and always getting the following errors:

> WARNING: Exiting before consuming the expected number of messages:
>   timeout (100000 ms) exceeded. You can use the --timeout option to
>   increase the timeout.

my command:

```
./kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --topic perf_test --broker-list $myhost:9092 --messages 10000000 --threads 2 --print-metrics --show-detailed-stats
```

Comment: Did you produce message to this topic?

Comment: I already produced messages to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid such warning, you have to at least produce 10000000 messages to that topic before running this command.

Comment: I already produced the 10000000  messages. I ran the producer perf test, than the consumer perf test

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 reasons for this:

1. Your Kafka instance cannot consume 10000000 messages with 2 threads in 100 seconds due to being overloaded. You can consider:

   - [monitoring your Kafka instance](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html) to see what's going on under the hood
   - increasing number of reader threads
   - increasing timeout
2. There are no messages in the topic you're trying to read and the reader tries to consume anticipated number of messages and fails / exits after 1 minute 40 seconds

You might also be interested in using a dedicated load testing tool, i.e. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), out of box it doesn't support Kafka load testing, but it can be enabled via [Pepper-Box](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box) plugin. Check out [Apache Kafka - How to Load Test with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-kafka-how-to-load-test-with-jmeter/) article for details.

Using a load testing tool you will provide way more information, you will be able to see [tables/charts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) with performance metrics allowing to correlate increasing load with increasing number of messages in topic queuing up or broker resource consumption